How to replace string in current HTML page using jquery or javascript
I want to replace a string in the HTML which is loaded in browser. Is it possible to do that using jQuery or JavaScript?
I know there is method to replace as below but how do I perform this operation on the HTML in current page?
string.replace(searchValue, replaceValue)

